# type of function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Problem with types in Haskell.
I try to move from Prolog to Haskel.
I have to calculate arithmetic expression from string representation. I have wrote recursive algorithm on Haskel, which match to Prolog program. Cause Haskel require that all elements in list must be of one type, it is impossible to mix operations signs with numbers, as in Prolog, so I use [String] type to represent arithmetic expression. For executing calculations, have to transform symbolic representation of numbers to Integer type, but result type inferred as float. Result of every operation must be inversely transformed to string, because it is type of string elements.
Haskell compiler (HUGS 98) hold off my program.
What is my error?

```
cc           :: (String b) => [String] -> b
cc (a:"*":b:t) = cc(c:t)
where c=show(read a * read b)
cc (a:"/":b:t) = cc(c1:t)
where c1=show(read a / read b)
cc (a:"-":t) = show(read a - read(cc t))
cc (a:"+":t) = show(read a + read (cc t))
cc (a:[])    = a
cc []    = 0
```

ERROR file:.\e3.hs:18 - Undefined class "String"

Comment: String is indeed not a class. What are you trying to express with `(String b) => [String] -> b`?

Comment: Bear in mind that in `a:'+':b:t` both a and b are single characters, so you will have some difficulties in calculating 10+12.

Comment: @n.m. ... that will not be an issues as it's not `'+'` but `"+"`  ;)

Comment: @Carsten Indeed. Didn't see it clearly on the phone.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler error is because of the `(String b) => ...` part in the first line which would indicate that `String` is a constraint on `b` - I don't think you wanted to express this here.

If I get you right you want a list of `String` and evaluate that to `Float` right?

In this case this should work as you expect it:

```
cc :: [String] -> Float
cc (a:"*":b:t) = cc (c:t)
  where c = show (read a * read b)
cc (a:"/":b:t) = cc (c1:t)
  where c1 = show (read a / read b)
cc (a:"-":t) = read a - cc t
cc (a:"+":t) = read a + cc t
cc (a:[])    = read a
cc []        = 0
```

As you can see I removed quite some of your `read`/`show` pairs as they are not needed anymore and simplified the signature quite a bit (there are already comments to that)

Here is an example:

```
λ> cc ["5","+","6","*","7"]
47.0
```

which seems to work ;)

---

PS: also note that you miss some cases like `cc ["10","10"]` in your patterns - maybe you should add an catch-all like:

```
cc _         = error "uh - what?"
```

to the end to get something like:

```
λ> cc ["10","12"]
*** Exception: uh - what?
```